# Calculated column in Laravel to transform name in slug

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a `Location` Model and Migration. Here I have `name`. Now I want to add an extra column (calculated), that will be `name` column with some replacement of special characters, and spaces to `-`. I will write that replace function by myself. I can't find a way of introducing calculated columns.
Thanks.

Comment: You might be looking for [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators). Also, Laravel has a helper `str_slug()` that might just do what you want.

Comment: @kerbholz
I put that code : 
    ` public function setSlugAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($value);
    }`

but when I do ` return  Location::find(1)->slug ` it returns me an empty page, while `Location::find(1)`  gives me all fields (except slug)

Comment: Change `setSlugAttribute()` to `getSlugAttribute()` (because you want to *get* that attribute), see if that works better. (Edit: and change your code accordingly to return the `str_slug()`)

Comment: Just realized my first comment might not have been that clear, what you are looking for are `Accessor`s, not `Mutators`

Comment: that works. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your model

```
protected $attributes = [
    'somecolumn'
];


public function getSomecolumnAttribute() {
    return str_slug($this->attributes['name'],'-');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = str_slug("Laravel 5 Framework", "-");
```

//output: laravel-5-framework
follow url for more helpers
    https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers

Comment: I added :
`      public function setSlugAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($value);
    }
`   to my Location Model.
When in controller to a specific page I run :
` return Location::find(1)->slug` it returns me empty page, meaning that, that value doesn`t exist. Why?